# JTable alternative for JSP

Tags: java, web-services, swing, jakarta-ee

I recently created an interactive Java Applet which communicates with the Google Maps API on a web page. Unfortunately Applets are a thing of the past (in my opinion) and I now need to convert a web page using an Applet into a JSP page which does not require an Applet.

My question is whether or not an API exists which can alternatively perform the same functions as a JTable (e.g. get data from database and display interactively)? I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question, however I am fairly new to web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot begged by your question such as:

Where is the database and what kind; is it local in the browser (SQLite) or remote?

If remote, do you have a web service that delivers the data via http request?

If not, and you are starting from scratch I would recommend looking at an AJAX helper like jQuery, MooTools or Dojo and Java Servlets/JSP/JSTL since you have a background in java.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Google Web Toolkit (GWT)

It is not exactly what you asking for, though. You code it as a Java Applet but using GWT's own subclasses and it gets translated into javascript.

Comment: This is great thank you, unfortunately I have to give mbarnes credit since Dojo had exactly what i was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

It may take some time to become familiar with a servlet-JSP approach. In the interim, consider converting your applet to a hybrid application, distributed via [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), as shown in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).

Comment: Thank you for the info, however my goal is to rid any client-side downloading/processes (excluding the web browser of course).